# Retrieving expiry date of codesigning certificates

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain

I am trying to find all the codesigning certificates I have in my login keychain (a lot), in order to print expiry date. I can find a long list of 46 identities with the command

```
security find-identity -p codesigning
```

But I have no clue how to get any further - reading any info from these identities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
security find-identity -p codesigning  > /tmp/allcerts.txt
grep -A100000 ' Valid identities only' /tmp/allcerts.txt > /tmp/validcerts.txt
rm /tmp/expiredates.csv
pattern='(\")'
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
    MYVAR=$line
    NAME=${MYVAR%\"*}
    NAME=${NAME#*\"}  # retain the part after the last slash
    DATEVAR=$(security find-certificate -c "$NAME" -p | openssl x509 -text | grep "Not After") 
    DATE=${DATEVAR#*:}
    echo $NAME,$DATE >> /tmp/expiredates.csv
  fi
    
done < /tmp/validcerts.txt
```